# How to execute SQL script in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I attempt to execute external SQL script in MySQL Workbench, but I get error:

```
Error executing SQL script.

Error executing "mysql.exe"

--defaults-extra-file=c:\users\301c~1\ap...\tmpjlo3w0.cnf

--protocol=tcp --port=3306 --host=localhost

--user=root:

[Error 267]
```

[image]

Please say me where is the cause of this error, and how can I solve it?

**NOTE:** MySQL was installed yesterday, so it is fresh installation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: A SQL script should contain, well, SQL code. Is that the case with yours?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, SQL script contains SQL code. I start my script from cmd, and it is executed successfully

Comment: It appears you're trying to execute `mysql.exe`, which I would think is the MySQL executable file.  ???

Comment: @BobJarvis no, I am trying to execute my own test.sql file, which was executed successfully from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

The same error happend on me. Finally find that the sql file is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the **full path** of sql script file to only the English path.